# Using a custom base URL for project pages

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm using Github pages/Jekyll for both my personal page as well as my project page.
I'm also using a custom domain, so something like `username.github.io` redirects to `mycustomdomain.com`.

Since I also have a `gh-pages` branch for my projects, my project's page lives at `mycustomdomain.com/myproject`.

However, I'd prefer if I could choose what this URL would be, for example, `mycustomdomain.com/projects/myproject`.

Is there any way to do this, without copy/pasting the whole project my `username.github.io` repository's `projects` folder?

Answer (score 4):

That should be [what baseurl is for](https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/).

[image: https://byparker.com/img/what-is-a-baseurl.jpg]

> - Set `baseurl` in your `_config.yml` to match the production URL without the host (e.g. `/example`, not `http://jekyll.github.io/example`).
> - Run `jekyll serve` and go to `http://localhost:4000/your_baseurl/`, replacing `your_baseurl` with whatever you set `baseurl` to in your `_config.yml`, and not forgetting the trailing slash.
> - Make sure everything works.
>     Feel free to prepend your urls with `site.baseurl`.
> - Push up to your host and see that everything works there, too!

Comment: `baseurl` doesn't actually change the site's location, right? I can set the `baseurl` in the project page, but it won't actually move the site to that URL.

Comment: As shown in the picture, baseurl is not the url, so the site location is unchanged.