# Embedding a dynamic app in a jekyll blog

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to embed a dynamic (Elm) app that has it's own routing into a jekyll blog. I load the app by adding a page in subdirectory that loads html that includes the javascript file holding the app.

However, the app has certain links that when clicked navigate to a path /some/path/123, where 123 is an id. The app then makes a request to fetch the relevant data and displays it.

This is where I run into trouble because Jekyll intercepts these redirects and the server displays a Not Found Error because there is no page setup for that path. Does anyone know how I might get around this problem? Otherwise, I suppose I will server the app on a subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

Jekyll isn't a server so it can't intercept any request, there is no page generated in the requested path (it just comes with a server for testing purposes).

Put Jekyll into a [sub directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40571887/1165509) and serve the other app as usual.